# Scrollable nav that is 100% div height

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am using bootstrap and I have a span2 on the left side of my page used as a nav.  Inside that nav is a list of items.  I would like that nav to be scrollable.  I would also like that nav to take up the remaining height of the page.

I don't want to absolutely position that nav I want it to stay a span2 (bootstrap), such that it flows to the top of the page when the width of the screen decreases.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="height: 150px;">
        Some Top level content
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        Here is my nav
<div id="navigation" class="scroll">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>

*{
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
}
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: Arimo, sans-serif;
}

a { color: #fff; }

.scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to tell a div in css to occupy the remaining height of the page, and then scroll within that?

Here is a fiddle to try and better explain the problem I am trying to solve.  You will notice that the page scrolls along with the nav.  I would like only the nav to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/newmanw/fbskugp7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

height: calc(100% - XXpx);

When XX is the height of the other elements of the page.

Comment: In your case: calc(100vh - 170px)

Comment: Awesome that is close.  However my page still scrolls up a little under the navbar.  Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/newmanw/fbskugp7/2/embedded/result/ Possible to prevent that?  I essentially have that same type of navbar at the top with bootstrap.

Comment: Here the updated fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/fbskugp7/4/
The problem is caused by the "Here is my nav" text.
I assume that text height is equal to 20px but this can vary.